# Create an array with specific string and how to divide the string into letter by letter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array and add a string to the array at zero index. I want to divide the string into separate letters (suppose I have the string `java`; I want to convert it into `j,a,v,a`). Is there any predefined methods for arrays in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Splitting a string is as easy as :

```
"hello".split("")
```

In order to insert an array into a array at a certain index, you have to use `splice`. For example:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4],
    hello = "hello".split("");

array.splice.apply(array, [0, 0].concat(hello));
```

The last line isn't that easy to understand at first. In javascript you can use `apply` on any function to call a function with parameters as array.

All it's doing is taking 0 element at index 0 in array and inserting the array `hello` at this position. You should read more about `split` and `splice`.

Splitting on an empty string will split on any character. But you can pass regex to split etc. So it's quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 var array = string.split(''); // where sting is your string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var str = 'java';
str.split(''); //["j", "a", "v", "a"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to achieve your requirement.

```
 var xArray=[];
 //Inserting a string at 0th index of an array
 xArray[xArray.length] = "JAVA";
 //Splitting that String with empty and joining the returned array with ","
 xArray[xArray.length - 1] =  xArray[xArray.length - 1].split("").join(",")

 alert(xArray[xArray.length - 1]); //J,A,V,A
```